# How to bind boost udp socket to specific interface

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

I've implemented a boost multicast UDP listener.

I want it to receive messages from a wireless device that sends multicast packets.

If I run my process, when the Ethernet cable is disconnected I receive the packets. However, if I start the process when the Ethernet cable is connected (hence 2 interfaces are available), I do not receive packets.

I tried to bind the socket to the local address but that didn't work.

Here is part of my code. Please let me know if you need more.

```
boost::asio::io_service ioService();
boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint multicastEP(multicastAddress, multicastPort);
boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint localEP(localAddress, multicastPort);
boost::asio::ip::udp::socket socket(ioService, localEP.protocol());

socket.set_option(boost::asio::ip::udp::socket::reuse_address(true));
socket.set_option( boost::asio::ip::multicast::enable_loopback(true));
socket.set_option(boost::asio::ip::multicast::join_group(multicastEP.address()));

socket.bind(boost::asio::ip::udp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address_v4::any(), multicastPort));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should be solved by system routing level because sockets it is an upper level that is no directly bind to network device... So approach to solve it - route prioritization and manipulation.